# Filter between dates VB.NET and Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007, oledb

As the title says, I'm unable to filter an SQL sentence from access database with vb.net

```
Dim data1 As String = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString
Dim data2 As String = DateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString
Dim sql As String = "SELECT totais.* From totais Where totais.data Between #" + data1 + "# And #" + data2 + "#;"
```

It gives me random values. If i put 1-10(October)-2019 it gives me all the records in system, if i put 12-10(October)-2019 it only gives today's  record (doesn't show yesterday and before records). I'm not finding the problem, can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: It might help if you include a sample of the data you're trying to query.

Comment: Gent Mecaj in the awnser below solved it, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use single quotes and convert type in SQL  like this:

```
SELECT totais.* FROM totais WHERE totais.data Between CDATE('" + data1 + "') And CDATE('" + data2 + "');"
```

Comment: That fixed it up, you are a genius, thank you my friend, lost my all day arround this :)

Comment: @JoséLopes The best way to thank someone on Stack Overflow is to accept their answer. You do this by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. The up pointing triangle above the number is an upvote which is also welcome but clicking the check mark is more points for Gent. You can do both. Also, you get 2 points for accepting an answer.

Comment: This is not the solution, as the format of the date strings will be localised, thus potentially fail in SQL. Either apply a fixed ISO format, or - preferably - use parameters as shown by Mary.

Answer (score 2):

I would use Parameters instead of concatenating a string for the Sql statement. It makes the statement much easier to read and avoids syntax errors.

With OleDb the order that parameters appear in the sql statement must match the order they are added to the parameters collection because OleDb pays no attention to the name of the parameter.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * From totais Where data Between @StartDate And @EndDate;"
    Using dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker2.Value
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: i will start using it, seems pretty simple that way to be honest thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use parameters as per Mary's answer BUT for completeness...

Ms/Access requires dates specified as #mm/dd/yy# so your SQL will only work properly where the local date time format is mm/dd/yy. i.e. mostly the US. Otherwise you will have to format your date string.