# Search by specific date in Access database with VB.net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, datetimepicker

I'm trying to search a date using DateTimePicker in an Access database and have the results show in the DataGridView but it doesn't work. No errors but it just doesn't show the database/results. Here's pictures of the database and the debugged form when it doesn't work in case they are of any use: [image: database] [image: form]

and here's my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form10
Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Daily Sales.accdb;")

Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
    If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        connection.Open()
    End If
    Dim dt1 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(DateTimePicker1.Value)
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Table1] where [TDateField] = #" & dt1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), connection)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    DataGridView2.DataSource = da
    connection.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Form10_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Missing closing hash - `& "#"`.

Comment: @KostasK. Just tried `("SELECT * FROM [Table1] where [TDateField] = #" & dt1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "#", connection)`, still doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter between dates VB.NET and Access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58489392/filter-between-dates-vb-net-and-access-database)

Comment: @June7 No, unfortunately. I'm trying to search one specific date, not between two dates.

Comment: The code demonstrated in answers would still be applicable (especially use of paramters). Just change the WHERE criteria to use single date instead of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the true date value of the datetime picker:

```vb
Dim dt1 As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Table1] where [TDateField] = #" & dt1.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & "#", connection)
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. Probably because in the database, the format is MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: DateTime values carry no format. If you store dates as text, modify the field to hold data type DateTime.

Comment: I see. Your solution didn't work but still, thank you.

Comment: It will work if the data type is DateTime. Dates should never be stored as text.

Comment: Doesn't this make the data type DateTime `Dim dt1 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(DateTimePicker1.Value)`?

Comment: It makes no sense to "parse" a DateTime value as it is numeric, and .Value is of data type DateTime.

Comment: So this makes it a DateTime `Dim dt1 As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value` or something else? Because I already did that and it didn't work.

Comment: No, it doesn't make it DateTime, as it already is DateTime. `dt1` just gets assigned the DateTime value of the date picker.

Comment: I got it, all's working now. I explored my code more and tried stuff but your solution also helped, thank you!

Comment: Would you care to share your solution ?